# Can't disable spring security for temporary (403 forbidden)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to disable spring security temporary for the whole application but I always get 403 forbidden

Deleting    @PreAuthorize annotation in my controller does not give any result. Endpoints that are not marked with this annotation also drop me 403 forbidden
I don't need basic auth i need no auth

My spring security config:
(/ ,  /api/**  ,  /**,  /* does not work, i always get 403 forbidden)

```
package com.project.webstation.Config;

import com.project.webstation.Services.CustomUserDetailsService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http
//                .csrf().disable()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/user/").permitAll()
//                .anyRequest()
//                .authenticated()
//                .and()
//                .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

One of my controllers:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user/")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserMap userMap;

    private final UserService userService;


    //@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Getting  user by the id")
    @GetMapping(value = "{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long Id) {
        User user = userService.findById(Id);
        UserResponse userResponse = userMap.userToResponse(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "getting  user data from request body and saving it to database")
    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<UserSaveResponse> saveUser(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
        User user = userService.save(userRequest);
        UserSaveResponse userSaveResponse = userMap.userToSaveResponse(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userSaveResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
    @ApiOperation(value = "getting  user data from request body and updating it in database(Admin method, can do it for all users)")
    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> updateUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal SecurityUser user, @RequestBody UserEditRequest userEditRequest, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        User updatedUser = userService.update(id, userEditRequest,user);
        UserResponse userResponse = userMap.userToResponse(updatedUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Deleting user by id from the database")
    @DeleteMapping(value = "{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> deleteUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal SecurityUser authenticatedUser,@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        userService.delete(id,authenticatedUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Getting all the Users from the database")
    @PostMapping(value = "get")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserResponse>> findAllWithFilters(@RequestBody UserFilterProperties userFilterProperties) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.getAllWithFilters(userFilterProperties),HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Subscribe on user")
    @PutMapping(value = "{id}/subscribe")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> subscribe(@RequestBody UserSubscriptionRequest userSubscriptionRequest, @AuthenticationPrincipal SecurityUser user, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
         userService.subscribe(id,user,userSubscriptionRequest);
         return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }


     @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
        @ApiOperation(value = "Unsubscribe from user")
        @PutMapping(value = "{id}/unsubscribe")
        public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> unsubscribe(@RequestBody UserSubscriptionRequest userSubscriptionRequest,@AuthenticationPrincipal SecurityUser user, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
            userService.unsubscribe(user,id,userSubscriptionRequest);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
        @ApiOperation(value = "Getting all user's subscribers")
        @GetMapping(value = "{id}/subscribers")
        public ResponseEntity<Set<UserResponse>> getSubscribers(@PathVariable("id") Long Id) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.getSubscribers(Id),HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    
        @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
        @ApiOperation(value = "Getting all user's subscriptions")
        @GetMapping(value = "{id}/subscriptions")
        public ResponseEntity<Set<UserResponse>> getSubscriptions(@PathVariable("id") Long Id) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.getSubscriptions(Id),HttpStatus.OK);
        }
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
    @ApiOperation(value = "upload file attached to the user")
    @PostMapping(value = "{userId}/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<User> uploadImage(@PathVariable("userId") Long id,
                                            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                            @AuthenticationPrincipal SecurityUser user) throws IOException
                                                {
        userService.saveImageForUser(id,file,user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: try changing "/" in your configuration to "/**". The "/" only allows requests for localhost and "/**" for all the underlying requests as well

Comment: @JAsgarov did not work

Comment: @JAsgarov I think it's "/api/**" not "/"

Comment: `permitAll` doesn't mean what you think it means. As you haven't enabled `anonymous` access it basically acts as `authenticated()`. The `permitAll` still requires an `Authentication` to be present and due to the lack of `anonymous()` access this can only be achieved through authentication.

Comment: @M.Deinum pls tell me how to set config to disable authorization(i want no auth)

Comment: I already explained that in my comment (which you didn't read fully). Enable anonymous access. Another way is to disable security in its totally by just removing this configuration. Or by overriding the `configure(WebSecurity)` method and specify for which URL to ignore everything (you will also need to disable the method security for that to work). I wonder why do you actually want to disable this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `SecurityConfig` class to completely ignore the specified url patterns...

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
}
```